# Sign pdf without private key

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

We've been asked for something that i think is not possible.

A webservice return a base64 string signature (not certificate or private key).

We've been asked to sign a pdf with that signature.

Is it possible to sign a pdf with that? we don't know very much of theoric of digital signature, every time we need to do someting like this we have a private key and a certificate valid, so we don't know if this is possible (and don't know either if make sense).

This is the code we have, we don't know how a String signature can fit here.

```
    public void sign(ByteArrayInputStream document, OutputStream os, String digestAlgorithm, String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason(reason);
        appearance.setLocation(location);
        appearance.setSignatureCreator(provider);
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 780), 1, "sig");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        List<Certificate> listCert = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
        listCert.add(this.getCertificate());
        Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[listCert.size()];
        chain = listCert.toArray(chain);
        ExternalSignatureContainer cont = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        cont.sign(document);
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, cont, 50);
    }
```

---

I update the answer in order to response Xavier.

We've no been asked to do any validation, i understand that it's the best and the main idea of digital signature, We have already asked valid certificate but have no response.

so, beyond that whether or not it makes sense, it is possible?

Comment: You write *"A webservice return a base64 string signature"* What was sent to that web services? I assume that you've sent a `byte[]` to the web service: can you describe those bytes? How were those bytes signed? Is the web service aware that it needs to sign the bytes so that the signed bytes can be inserted into a PDF? Your question is unanswerable as long as you don't answer these counter-questions.

Comment: The signature in a pdf can only be validated by certificates. So the question is more about 'how do you validate the signature?how can you have non repudiation (which is the main purpose of a digital signature)'

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Lowagie Thanks for the quick reply. We don't send a byte[]. The purppose of the webService is create a digital invoice, so we send a huge xml (that's why i didn't copy this request, but if it's helpful i will update de question) and the webservice response with the same xml adding the signature value. Yes the webServices know that the signature must be insert in a pdf

Comment: You write *We send a huge XML*. Is there a PDF file stored in the XML (for instance Base64 encoded)? The architecture you describe is awkward. Who was the architect (and can you fire him)?

Comment: No the pdf is not stored in the xml, the xml store only data, with the response we generate a jasper report.

Comment: Which information on the original pdf do you send in the XML? To sign the pdf you obviously have to send some information on it. And you say you get back a *base64 string signature*. "Base64 string" is not of interest, it's merely an encoding of binary data as string. But what kind of signature do you get? Plain signature value? Wrapped as pkcs1 signature? A full fledged cms/pkcs7 container?

Comment: 'Sign without a private key' is already a contradiction in terms.

Comment: *the pdf is not stored in the xml, the xml store only data, with the response we generate a jasper report.* - so you have the signature **before** you create the pdf? In that case the signature obviously cannot be used as signature of the PDF.

Comment: Re your edit, beyond whether it is possible, it doesn't make sense. Contradictions in terms are not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is generally not possible.

Signatures over content should indicate a specific signer and should be over specific content. If you could re-assign a signature then an attacker could do the same and claim that a *different* document was signed.

So there are two possibilities:

1. the XML contains exactly the content to be signed and placed in the PDF document (seems unlikely);
2. the signature is just to protect the XML information in transit.

The latter seems most likely. For instance web-services security  (WS-Security) can use XML based signatures.

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually we were sending us information and returning a response with a signature already generated, we had asked us to use the same signature on a pdf generated by the application, why the firm ceased to make sense.